# Full Calendar Events not getting displayed

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I am having some trouble in displaying the events on fullcalendar. Can someone please help?
it was working fine till I introduced the end date here in database. I have already tried by removing it from calendar but it still doesn't work.

I am trying to bind json data returned by my mvc controller. The Json looks fine and is coming as:

```
{ id = 1, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-02T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-06T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true }  

{ id = 3, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-03T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-10T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true }
{ id = 4, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-04T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-07T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true }
{ id = 5, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-07T00:00:00.0000000", end = null, allDay = true }
{ id = 6, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-08T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-08T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true }
{ id = 7, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-09T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-15T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true }
```

On load returning the custom error:

> "Error while Getting events!"

This is the calendar I have

```
var calendar = {
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today, basicDay,basicWeek,month'

    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    buttonText: {
        today: 'Today',
        day: 'Day',
        week: 'Week',
        month: 'Month',
        prev: 'Prev', 
        next: 'Next', 

    },
    weekends: true, 
    editable: true,
    events: {
        url: 'FullCalendar/GetEvents',
        color: 'yellow',
        error: function () {
            alert('Error while Getting events!');
        }
    }
};
myCalendar.fullCalendar(calendar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not fine. It should look like this:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"XYZ Apple","start":"2013-10-02T00:00:00.0000000","end":"2013-10-06T00:00:00.0000000","allDay":"true"},
{"id":"3","title":"XYZ Apple","start":"2013-10-03T00:00:00.0000000","end":"2013-10-10T00:00:00.0000000","allDay":"true"}]
```

You can validate your JSON at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: The problem seems to be the the URL for the source is getting rendered. When i am using the url as "GetEvents" and running the app from that same root it works and i am doing that for now.

Answer (score 0):

In your json data try this `"allDay":"false"`.
May be it will help you. If it not works then put your json data statically and try to find out where you are wroung.

```
events: [
{ id = 1, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-02T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-06T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true },  

{ id = 3, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-03T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-10T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true },
{ id = 4, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-04T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-07T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true },

{ id = 6, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-08T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-08T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true },
{ id = 7, title = "XYZ Apple", start = "2013-10-09T00:00:00.0000000", end = "2013-10-15T00:00:00.0000000", allDay = true }]
```